# Responsive Div Width

Tags: css, grid, width, responsiveness

I `want to make several 'blocks' of text go from this:

```
|1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |6|
```

When viewed on a screen wider than a tablet, to be responsive according to the smaller screen size, like this:

On tablet:

```
| 1 | | 2 | | 3 |

| 4 | | 5 | | 6 |
```

On mobile:

```
|1|

|2|

|3|

|4|

|5|

|6|
```

Here is the weblink to the page:

[create.qublu.com/rates](http://create.qublu.com/rates)

The full width of the page is 980px. What I need is for each div to have a responsive width according to the screen size viewed and to be centered on the screen.

As you will see on the page, there are four toggle buttons. Level 1, Level 2, Level 3 and Level 4. Level 2 works absolutely fine and perfect. But all the blocks on Level 1 just aren't lining up when viewed on large screens. Instead, the blocks are displaying 3 blocks x 2 rows. Very frustrating!

This is the CSS code I am using:

```
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.47%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.47%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-7 {
    width: 58.47%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.47%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-9 {
        width: 75%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.74%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.74%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-11 {
    width: 91.74%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.74%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    width: 99%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-12 {
    width: 99%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-12 {
    width: 99%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-12 {
        width: 99%;
        float: left;
    }
}
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 321px) {
.col-sm-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 699px) {
.col-md-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
.col-lg-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

To have 6 columns in one row you can use **col-XX-2** - where XX is the screen size abbreviation

In your example "**col-md-2**" used as class for your level-1 divs will result in:

|1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |6|

Comment: Hi David, yup have tried that. But then it jumps from being 6 columns for a large screen, to only one column for mid screen sizes and down. Ok for mobile screens, not ok for tablet sizes. For some reason it doesn't like having multiple classes assigned to the div. So atm I have it set to: <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">